# Authlogic_OpenID - "uninitialized constant Rack::OpenID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, authlogic, ruby-1.9

So I followed the railscast tutorial (http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic) and used the old version of the plugin from Ryan's git file. I can now successfuly create/register a user using OpenID (Google), but I cannot log in with this user. When I submit the OpenID that has been registered, I get "uninitialized constant Rack::OpenID". Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I also had this problem. I found the reason a while ago. I think the openid plugin was out of date or something... I just remember thinking that it wasn't worth dealing with and went with a different solution. There are other gems that might be better though. Try devise (look it up on Ryan's site)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying the latest version of the plugin, or the gem.

Things change quick in rails, and old code can break with new versions of rails.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying Devise, it is easier for integrate OpenId, Facebook, Tweeter ...
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise